# Authenticating PDF streaming via Laravel API

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel API that generates a pdf. I am using laravel passport for the pdf. I want to stream the pdf in the browser not download it. I currently generate a pdf but it  is open to the world, anybody would be able to to access the pdf. I want to add authentication for it. A user should be able to see his/her pdfs generated by my app and not any other user's pdfs.

My idea so far is to generate a personal access token for the user and pass it via the url.

Is this a good idea? Any other ideas I should consider on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel authentication to stop unauthorized access to routes, here is the documentation how you can do that,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication